# Scape gtag/jquery variables with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

**TL/DR - How to I get the price value from the code at the bottom of this post? ( 'price': '124.99', )**

Hello I am trying to create a python **scraper** and I have the code below from following tutorials:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = ''

headers = {
"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36 Edg/93.0.961.44'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
print(soup.prettify())
```

The print returns a lot but the variable I am trying to parse appears like this:

```
 <!-- WooCommerce JavaScript -->   <script type="text/javascript">    jQuery(function($) {

                        $( '.single_add_to_cart_button' ).on( 'click', function() {
```

..... skip 50+ lines

```
                    $( '.products .post-4381 a' ).on('click', function() {
                            if ( true === $(this).hasClass( 'add_to_cart_button' ) ) {
                                    return;
                            }
                            gtag( 'event', 'select_content', {
                                    'content_type': 'product',
                                    'items': [ {
                                            'id': '4381',
                                            'name': 'Broad Spectrum',
                                            'category': 'Tanning Oil&amp; Isolates',    
                                         'list_position': '9'

                                    } ], y': 'Oil/&amp; ',
                                    'price': '124.99',
                            } ]
                    } );
```

How would I extract the **price** value from here? It is the only thing named price on this page

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: @MendelG URL = 'https://www.reefersbay.com/product/bulk-delta-8-oil-100-grams/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price is inside `class="price-wrapper"` tag:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.reefersbay.com/product/bulk-delta-8-oil-100-grams/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

price = soup.select_one(".price-wrapper ins").text
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
$124.99
```

---

If you want price as a float:

```py
print(float(price.replace("$", "")))
```

Prints:

```
124.99
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would upvote but I don't have 15 reputation yet. I'm pretty new to python but I was trying to figure this out for a bit and couldn't figure it out. 

I think I understand it now, it looks like its looking for the ins tag within the price-wrapper div and removing all the html stuff in-between. thanks! Does select_one just grab the first one from top to bottom?